# modify the data entry in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

When i am editing the entry it will going back to the form but soon it hit enter the null values are being saved.

I don't know why this is happening. Please check
I think it can be because you are not pushing the whole object (name title and name value) to your 'cart' list, so when retrieving the item to edit, you don't get the all the values, you only get the text

[Code is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGQXog9D66nWAAzarToF?p=preview)

html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head >
    <title>
        JustRelief | e-store
    </title>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }

  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .message {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #868686;
  }

  .typeahead-demo .custom-popup-wrapper > .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    min-width: 160px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
</style>


</head>
<body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
<div id="section1">

    <div class="nav1">
        <img src="img/logo1.png" class="logo">

        <div id="bars">
            <a  class="fa fa-bars  white " data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"
            ></a>
        </div>
                </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list ">
        <li><a href="#" class="list-txt"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> Track Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="list-txt"><span class="fa fa-book    "></span> Complaints</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="list-txt"><span class="fa fa-comment "></span> Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="list-txt"><span class="fa fa-user    "></span> Customer Care</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>








<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 center1">
            <div class="col-xs-12  ">
                <h4 class="text-center txtC1">Enter your medicines</h4> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <!--<input type="text" uibtypeahead="state as state.x for state in states | filter:{x.$viewValue}" ng-model="enteredName" id="tags"/> -->


 <input type="text" ng-model="enteredName" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.w for state in states | filter:{w:$viewValue}" id="tags"/ >


                <p>{{enteredName.w}}</p>
                <p ng-model="e1">{{enteredName.p}}</p>

            </div>
<br/>&nbsp
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">




<p class="rr txtC2">Type</p>
<div class="rr">
                    <select id="dd" ng-model="sel">
                        <option value="Days">Days</option>
                        <option value="Tabs">Tab</option>
                        <option value="Packs">Pack</option>
                    </select>



</div>
<p class="rr txtC2">Qty</p>

                <input type="number" class="rr" ng-model="ww" id="dd"/> 



            </div>


    <br/>&nbsp
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">

                <button id="btn2" ng-Click="addName()">Add</button>
                <button id="btn2">Order</button>
            </div>      




    <br/>&nbsp

<div class="col-xs-12">
<p class="txtC1">Cart<hr></p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 dd1" >


<div>
<p class="tt" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name.x1}}  x {{name.qty}} = Rs.{{name.p1 * name.qty}}

<a class="fa fa-close tt1" ng-click="removeName(name)"> Remove</a>
            <a class="fa fa-edit tt1" ng-click="edit(name)"> Edit</a></p></div>





    <div>







        </div>              
    </div>

</div>




</div>








<div id="section2"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);


 app.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = [
 {"w":"Combiflame", "p":"45"},
{"w":"Crocine", "p":"50"},
{"w":"Alphine", "p":"52"},
{"w":"Nitro", "p":"71"},
{"w":"Betnisol", "p":"79"},
{"w":"Daily Dose", "p":"88"},
{"w":"EyeTone", "p":"95"},
{"w":"Kyrotop", "p":"101"}


];

console.log($scope.states[1].x)


if($scope.ww != ''){
         $scope.names = [


        ];}
        else{

        }


        $scope.addName = function() {

    console.log (  $scope.names)    

if($scope.ww != ''){



   $scope.names.push({'x1':$scope.enteredName.w,'tp':$scope.sel,          'qty':$scope.ww, 'p1':$scope.enteredName.p});

            $scope.enteredName = [];
 $scope.ww = '';
 $scope.tp = '';


}else
{

}



        };

        $scope.removeName = function(name) {
          var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
          $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        };





      $scope.edit = function(name){

           var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);

    $scope.enteredName.w =  $scope.enteredName 

   $scope.enteredName    = name.x1; 
    $scope.sel = name.tp;
    $scope.ww = name.qty;

           $scope.names.splice(i, 1);


      }


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were not assigning the correct properties in your `edit` function. The following code is working. This uses ES6. You may need to shim `.find` or iterate another way, but the main thing is to use the right item from `$scope.states`.

```
  $scope.edit = function(name, idx){
    // assign the matching item from `$scope.states`
    $scope.enteredName = $scope.states.find((item) => item.p === name.p1);
    $scope.sel = name.tp;
    $scope.ww = name.qty;
    $scope.names.splice(idx, 1);
  }
```

I also optimized your code by passing the `$index` from the template where it is already available. You don't need to calculate it in the `edit` function.

```
<a class="fa fa-edit tt1" ng-click="edit(name, $index)"> Edit</a>
```

[**Click here for live demo (modern browsers).**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtKU4dDYl5pcOAxirUJ5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @m59 ....but the value is not passing in the text box while hitting the edit box.....

Comment: @SaurabhDellaRa'Man Oops. Updated.

Comment: but can you please help me in  1 more thing...please....I need to total price which is there in {{name.p1}} next to the CART text .....